# Sounds using audio in my simple javascript game won't play

Tags: javascript, audio

The following is an excerpt from my little game (which all works apart from the sound, no errors in Chrome either, console.log proves code is run)???

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Final Game Code + HS RA</title>
</head> 
<body>
<script>

var myAudio = new Audio();
myAudio.source = "Sounds/Impact_1.mp3";
myAudio.volume = 1;

// a bunch of code for the game that all works goes here including a function that calls the below...

nanonautTouchedARobot = true;
myAudio.load();
myAudio.play();  // play the sound #############################################
// below line is just test code to prove progress on the console
console.log('OUCH!'); 

// a bit more code for the game that all works goes here...

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myAudio.source = "Sounds/Impact_1.mp3";
```

This is incorrect.  You want the `src` property:

```
myAudio.src = 'Sounds/Impact_1.mp3';
```

Additionally, you don't need `.load()` before `.play()` like that.  And, ensure that you're calling `.play()` on a user action so that you don't run afoul of autoplay policies.

Comment: Thanks, such a simple thing (I'm coding in notepad so not much help there)